# Tidying up when closing Swing application

Tags: java, swing

Not really that familiar with Swing, and am writing a client-server UDP chat application. Everything is working fine, except I would like my clients to send a notification to the server and to close the DatagramSocket when their windows are closed. Where do I put my code so that it executes upon closing the window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Register a [`WindowAdapter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html) to the container and override it's [`windowClosing`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html#windowClosing%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29) method.

---

### Example

```
foo.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

where `foo` is your container instance.

Comment: Alright so I assume I have to write a concrete class that extends WindowAdapter, how do I register it to my JFrame?